# how do i to make a window(osx) always hover on top of screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

i trying to make a osx application that just have one window and it will always on the top of screen.
anyone knows how to achieve it? thanks.

Comment: Before you do this, consider very carefully whether it really is the Right Thing.  You should at least make it a feature that the user switches on and off.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can change the window's windowLevel (via -setLevel:) to NSFloatingWindowLevel.

```
[window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

Documentation is here: [Window_Levels](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/window_levels)

Answer (score 1):

By "on the top", do you mean you do not want your window to be obscured, even if a different app is active?  In that case, one way is to start with the NSPanel template in Interface Builder, check the "Utility" option, and uncheck "Hide on Deactivate".