# Setting the window level over Accessibility

Tags: macos, objective-c

I'm working on a Mac OS X application which manipulates a window belonging to another app. I use Accessibility for that.

I have already succeeded to move the window and query its properties from my app. Now I need to make the window stay "always on top". Based on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278208/how-do-i-to-make-a-windowosx-always-hover-on-top-of-screen) I need to set the window level to NSFloatingWindowLevel. Is that possible over the Accessibility API? I don't see any [Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXAttributeConstants_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) or [Carbon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/Reference/reference.html) attribute that would correspond to the window level.

Comment: Hi Jezevec, were you able to figure this out, I am in the same situation now. (althought ideally i want to do it without accessibility api)